# entering checkbox value into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have the following checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" value="Monday" /> Monday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" value="Tuesday" /> Tuesday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" value="Wednesday" /> Wednesday </br>
<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" value="Thursday" /> Thursday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" value="Friday" /> Friday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" value="Saturday" /> Saturday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="weekday[]" value="Sunday" /> Sunday &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

I would like to enter all the checked values into "day" field in mysql separated by coma,

please help

Comment: To get you started, `$_POST['weekday']` will be an array containing the checkboxes selected. If nothing is selected, `isset($_POST['weekday'])` will be false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit_btn_name']))
   {
      $days="";

      if(isset($_POST['weekday']))
      {

          foreach($_POST['weekday'] as $id)
          {
                $days.=$id.",";
          }
              $days = substr($days, 0, -1);

      }

      echo $days;

   }
```

**EDIT**
this is in response to the comment about the query to post the $days variable as I found it difficult to format code in the comments.

```
  $sql1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO class (class_id, subject_id, student_id, available_days, available_time, status) VALUES ('".$class_id."','".$subject_id."','".$student_id."','".$days."','".$available_t‌​ime."','pending')"‌​)or die('Error: There was error while submitting the schedule, please try again.');
```

Comment: data does enter into mysql day field using this method, however i also get a parse error  Undefined variable: days

Comment: sorry this code doesnt show errors in my end.. can you tell the line  where the error is shown..

Comment: i get it while trying to run sql query to insert value stored in $days into day field of mysql

Comment: can you post the mysql_query also .. actually that error should not show if the variable $days is set already

Comment: $sql1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO class (class_id, subject_id, student_id, available_days, available_time, status)
   VALUES
   ('$class_id','$subject_id','$student_id','$days','$available_time','pending')");
   
   if (!mysql_query($sql1))
   {
   die('Error:  There was error while submitting the schedule, please try again.');
   exit;
     }

Comment: i get this die error actually, but data enters successfully into mysql

Comment: try this block of code instead of that code you posted..      -- --------------------------- $sql1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO class (class_id, subject_id, student_id, available_days, available_time, status) VALUES ('".$class_id."','".$subject_id."','".$student_id."','".$days."','".$available_time."','pending')"‌​)or die('Error: There was error while submitting the schedule, please try again.');

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
implode(',',$_POST['weekday'])
```

?

Comment: `field in mysql separated by coma,`

Comment: where is the contradiction in my answer?

Comment: Trivial: would that be ['weekday']...no 's'?

Comment: @dave noted and corrected. next time feel free to suggest an update to my post.

Answer (score 0):

For searching you should `implode(',' , $_POST['weekday'])` and use

```
$sql = "select * from table where day in ('" . implode("','" , $_POST['weekday']) . "')";
```

in sql query

Comment: @Rikudo-Sennin What do you mean?

Comment: what I mean is, you have code in your answer which isn't inside of code tags.

Comment: I put only direction for writing proper code. So I don't see cause for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

you will get $_POST['weekday'] as an array. you can use it like

```
$_POST['weekday'][0];
$_POST['weekday'][1];
$_POST['weekday'][2];
$_POST['weekday'][3];
$_POST['weekday'][4];
$_POST['weekday'][5];
$_POST['weekday'][6];
```

Comment: -1. not accurate. it won't display values for the checkboxes which aren't checked.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
$arr = array();

// check for CHECKED checkboxes
for(var $i = 0; $i > count($_POST['weekday']); $i++){
   // if this checkbox is checked
   if (isset($_POST['weekday'][$i])) { 
       $arr[] = $_POST['weekday'][$i];
   }
}

// convert to comma separated
$checkbox_str = implode(',', $arr);
```

Now you can use `$checkbox_str` to save in the database.

Comment: incorrect. Only checked checkboxes are sending the post to request

Comment: It'd be faster to do `$checkbox_str = implode(',', $_POST['weekday']);`

Comment: i get this error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR, expecting ';'

Comment: Also you dont put `count` in the `for`-loop since it will calculate the count for every iteration.